# Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith vs. The Clone Wars

Tags: star-wars, continuity, the-clone-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

According to [wiki on Wikipedia about Star Wars canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon):

> The official Star Wars canon consists of the seven released Star Wars theatrical feature films, the Star Wars animated film and television series **The Clone Wars** and Star Wars Rebels, and any other material released after April 25, 2014, unless otherwise stated.

I watched *The Clone Wars* television series and always thought that it happens between Episode II and Episode III, but when whatching Episodes II and III again, I became confused...

What about Grievous in the 3rd episode movie not recognizing Anakin? Was *The Clone Wars* "forced" to become canonical or are there some arguments to explain it?

<sub>*Note, *The Clone Wars* is not in continuity or canon with *Clone Wars* it's spiritual predecessor cartoon series.</sub>

Comment: it wasn't "forced" to become canonical, but the show was created after the movie, so all of grievous and anakin's actions during the clone wars are technically a retcon.

Comment: Ok, but if Disney consider the Clone Wars cartoon canonical, they would have some arguments to maintain their decision, I think so, or they would explain later...

Comment: Looking at [Grievous' bio on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous), I'm actually not seeing any instances where Anakin and Grievous actually met during the Clone Wars series. There are instances where they were in the same location, but Obi-Wan was always the one to fight Grievous while Anakin completed other tasks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not *entirely* sure what your question is here, but to confirm: *The Clone Wars* takes place between Epsiodes II and Episodes III. Lucas has confirmed this himself [in interviews](http://www.getfrank.co.nz/editorial/features/interview-george-lucas-executive-producer-of-the-clone-wars):

> **Q:** Why is it important for you to tell the story of The Clone Wars?
>
> **A:** The interesting thing about the Clone Wars is that in the films, in
> the normal course of the Skywalker saga, it’s skipped over. You hear
> about it, but you only see the very beginning and the very end of the
> wars. ***But this was a turning point for the Republic. Star Wars: The
> Clone Wars connects Episodes II and III.  As a TV series, it gives
> more depth and understanding about how Republic fell, and what a
> fantastic hero Anakin Skywalker was.***  We got focused on him turning
> into Darth Vader, that it’s easy to forget that he was one of the
> biggest heroes of the entire Clone War. I think seeing him as a great
> Jedi Knight reminds you that before it gets dark and tragic, Star Wars
> is a fun adventure story, too.

With regards to the General Grievous / Anakin Skywalker continuity errors (i.e. them not knowing each other), I'm not aware of any time in the prequels they actually *met*. They may have been *aware* of each other, but that doesn't mean they'd recognise each other.

Of course, that doesn't mean there aren't *other* discrepancies in the series. Our friends over at the [Sci Fi Stack](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23814/what-continuity-problems-have-star-wars-the-clone-wars-created) have had a question on major continuity problems created by the series and responded with a few. To lift and shift them from the posted link:

> From: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Retcon
>
> "Since Episode IV, the Republic was known to have fought the Clone
> Wars, and the EU added several other conflicts, such as the Great Sith
> War; but in Episode II, it was stated that "there hasn't been a
> full-scale war since the formation of the Republic." The
> above-mentioned Ruusan Reformation also handled this discrepancy."
>
> "Timothy Zahn, in his Thrawn trilogy, cast the Clone Masters as the
> opponent of the Galactic Republic in the Clone Wars, as several
> authors of the '90s considered that the cloners and their clones were
> the "villains." However, after Attack of the Clones revealed the
> clones were on the Republic's side, the Clone Masters were retconned
> into being renegades who did not attack until after the formation of
> the Empire."
>
> From:
> http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(TV_series)
>
> "One example of a direct contradiction between The Clone Wars and
> Clone Wars is the use of Eta-2 Actis-class light interceptors at the
> same point in the timeline Anakin is knighted, whereas in The Clone
> Wars Delta-7B Aethersprite-class light interceptors are used, which
> were ostensibly used before the later Eta-2s. "
>
> "For example, in the novelization, Anakin remarks that he has only
> read about Grievous' Magnaguards in an intel report, despite having
> fought them in the show."
>
> "Another very noticeable continuity error is the fact that Anakin has
> his scar which he received shortly after the Battle of Rendili from
> Asajj Ventress. He then injured Ventress so severely she was forced to
> recuperate until the Battle of Boz Pity, after which she deserts the
> CIS and the war for good. However, as he was originally shown to
> receive his scar in 19 BBY, yet the series takes place in 21 BBY, this
> is a glaring continuity error."
>
> **Thanks to @Sam for these.**

I think that ultimately, in a *universe* of this size, discrepancies are bound to occur. The largest, most noticeable ones were [retconned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity). The others were likely not.